# How to parse a Linux terminal error message in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I have written a small Python code to test it for a bigger project. The subprocess works great if everything's fine. But I want to parse the output error message for particular errors so I can figure out what the error is such as- IP not in network, or wrong username, wrong password.
Even the print at the end doesnt work. My interest in however not to print those. I was merely checking if the parsing works!

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os 
ip = "192.168.1.20"
password = "password"
username = "sam"
ans = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','xfreerdp','-p',password, ip])
    for line in ans.split('\n'):
        if "protocol security negotiation" in line:
            print "Not Windows!"
print "JUST TO test if this print works and it doesnt!!"
```

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: i am using Python 2.7

Comment: Running your code but using double quotes plays nice - give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using try..except

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os 
ip = "192.168.1.20"
password = "password"
username = "sam"
try:
    ans = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','xfreerdp','-p',password, ip])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    ans = e.output
for line in ans.split('\n'):
    if "protocol security negotiation" in line:
        print "Not Windows!"
print "JUST TO test if this print works and it doesnt!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect STDERR in order to check messages printed to it. Add:

`subprocess.check_output(['sudo','xfreerdp','-p',password, ip], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`